# Not able to understand what does find-set(x) in algorithm is

Tags: graph-algorithm

FIND-SET(x) – returns the representative or a pointer to the representative of the set that contains element x.

In algorithms find-set(x) is used in disjoint data structures. I don't understand the use of this function. Suppose I have a graph with 4 vertices, a,b,c,d and the weights given as a-b=4, b-c=5, c-d=6 ... How does find-set(u)!=find-set(v) (where u,v are any vertices of the graph) help me define the occurrence of a cycle in the graph!?? Find is defined as:

```
function Find(x)
     if x.parent == x
        return x
     else
        return Find(x.parent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find-Set(x)` is used in disjoint data structures most frequently to implement Minimum Spanning Trees (MST).

If `u` and `v` are in the same set, it means that they are already **connected**. If they are already **connected**, then adding *another* connection between them creates a **cycle**.

We can begin analyzing this by saying that all vertices are within their own distinct, single-element sets. When we establish a connection between two vertices e.g. `a-b`, then we put `a` and `b` within the same set. Consequently, we need to determine how they're in the same set; thus, we use `Find-Set(x)` to determine if they are within the same set (in your case, it's a disjoint forest implementation).

The example you provide does not have a cycle, so I'll add another edge:

### Example

Initially, assume we have a set of vertices `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. We want to determine the minimum spanning tree such that there is the minimum number of edges possible to connect all three vertices to the same forest.

Edges available now:
`(a, b)`, `(c, d)`, `(b, c)`, `(d, c)` (extra edge which is a cycle!)

*This assumes you know the definitions of vertex, edge and forest which are all fundamental graph terms*

Since `a` and `b` are currently distinct sets, we can combine them through an algorithm such as `Merge-Set(a, b)` which places them within the same set: `A=(a, b)` while there are still `c` and `d` that must be connected. *Note here that `A` is the name of the set*

We can see that `(c, d)` is also possible; so, we can merge them: `B=(c, d)` and we also have `(a, b)`. *`B` is the name of this disjoint set*

Now we can merge `A=(a, b)` and `B=(c, d)` by knowing that we have edge `(b, c)`. Since there are multiple elements within the set, we first determine whether the edge is necessary through `Find-Set(x)`. If `Find-Set(b) == Find-Set(c)` then we know we have a cycle i.e. if `A == B`. Fortunately, we do not since `(b, c)` does not occur within either set `A=(a, b)` or `B=(c, d)`. Now we merge them as usual and arrive at our MST which is a set: `A=(a, b, c, d)` (note that B has been deleted!).

Recall our extra edge which is to be a cycle now. If we attempt to add `(d, c)`, we see that the set which `d` and `c` reside in are the same i.e. `Find-Set(d) == Find-Set(c)` or `A == A` since `d` and `c` are both in set `A`. Consequently, we can determine that this edge creates a cycle!

Comment: gio borje: Which set does Find-Set(x) looks for the comparision? :s

Comment: @user975234, Bear with me for a moment since I'll try to write up a clear example.

Comment: sure.. Please do that .. I have been really struggling with this. If possible please do with this example of kruskal here: http://goose.ycp.edu/~dbabcock/PastCourses/cs360/lecture/lecture20.html

Comment: i got ur example.. but if we consider this one: http://goose.ycp.edu/~dbabcock/PastCourses/cs360/lecture/lecture20.html .. then .. the edge (2,3) makes a cycle .. i am not able to relate this with the explanation u gave :|

Comment: Okay .. i finally got it! :) Thanks a lot for the answer ! :D

Comment: At step 3, `(1, 2, 3)` are within the same set as denoted by the edge connections. `2` and `3` reside within the same set so the edge does not need to be added to our MST i.e. we can skip it because they're already connected indirectly.